# Creating a list of PopupMenus that dynamically update an element in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, dynamic

So as the title says I am trying to make a list where each element is determined by a users choice of an element in a PopupMenu.

My first attempt:

```
test = Table["A", {5}];
Table[PopupMenu[Dynamic[test[[n]]], {"A", "B", "C"}], {n, 5}]
```

Returned the following error

```
Part::pspec: Part specification n is neither an integer nor a list of integers.
```

For some reason the dynamic(?) would not allow me to refer to specific elements in the list. I then tried to circumvent this issue by introducing an extra variable *temp*:

```
Table[temp = n;PopupMenu[Dynamic[test[[temp]]], {"A", "B", "C"}], {n, 5}]
```

However, all this did was create 5 PopupMenus that all referred to the $5^{\text{th}}$ element of the list *test*. I tried to put a `Setting[]`  around the `Dynamic[]`, but since that removes that effect of `Dynamic[]` nothing happened at all.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to work :

```
test = Table["A", {5}];

PopupMenu[Dynamic[test[[#]]], {"A", "B", "C"}, "A"] & /@ Range[5] // Row

Dynamic @ test

(* {"C", "A", "B", "A", "C"} *)
```

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use:

```
 test = Table["A", {5}];
 Table[With[{n = n}, PopupMenu[Dynamic[test[[n]]], {"A", "B", "C"}]], {n, 5}]
```

or

```
 Table[PopupMenu[Dynamic[test[[k]]], {"A", "B", "C"}] /. k -> n, {n, 5}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer as well! Just one question though; how come the `With[{n=n},.....]` works?

Comment: @E.O., `With[{n=n},..]` is used to replace all instances of the local variable `n` with its corresponding value ("so that the values of the `Table` iterator variable are passed  into the dynamic expression"). See [How to Evaluate Expressions inside Dynamic or Manipulate](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/EvaluateExpressionsInsideDynamicOrManipulate.html) for several examples on the reason why it is needed and works here.